# Angular: how to create reusable layout or template for dynamic context and functionality?

Tags: css, angular

The layout of the app I develop is standard:

It looks like that:

[image]

```
// app.component.html

<router-outlet>
```

```
// main.component.ts

<div class="main-container">
    <app-header></app-header>

    <div class="app-main">
        <div class="router-outlet-container">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div class="side-bar">
            <app-side-bar></app-side-bar>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to add a header for each page, by page I mean router outlet component.
The header has the same layout but differant actions and context. It also need to comunicate the main content of that component.

To implement the requirements, I thought using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to control the page header from the global scss file.

### Question

Is there a better implementation in angular for that?
I know this question might consider as opinion based, but my meaning is to explore angular techniques I might not heard of.

Code example:

```
//project-list.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'app-project-list',
    templateUrl: './project-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./project-list.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ProjectListComponent implements OnInit
```

```
// project-list.component.scss

app-project-list {
...
// component styles
}
```

```
// project-list.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="projects$ | async as projects">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="page-header-inner">
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-main">
        
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

```
// styles.scss

.router-outlet-container {
    & > *:not(router-outlet) {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        .page-header {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            padding: 16px;
            .page-header-inner {
                height: 56px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding: 0px 24px;
            }
        }
        .page-main {
            padding: 0 24px;
            flex: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how you're making this work at all, are you fixed positioning the header to cover the default? cause that sounds pretty janky. you need to be careful with view encapsulation none because the styles stay after the component is destroyed, so you can create weird bugs and conflicts. I think you need to give a concrete example of what the header looks like and what you're trying to replace.

Comment: I have no experience working without encapsulation, that is why I agree with you about the junkiness. I'm looking for a solution to reuse styled template inside components and cross components.
By "default" you mean the div with class `page-main`? I set display flex to the component host, the `page-header` have fixed height and `page-main` flex: 1.

Comment: I edited the question with the full styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but I think you just want to make an `app-inner-header` component of some kind with this template that uses `ng-content` to transclude dynamic content:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header-inner">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

apply whatever styles you want in the associated styles file. and then in your components you can transclude your content...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="projects$ | async as projects">
    <app-inner-header>
      <!-- just put your content here, it will appear where you put the ng-content tag -->
    </app-inner-header>

    <div class="page-main">
        
    </div>
</ng-container>
```